# exact string in perl subtitute

Tags: regex, string, perl, match

I'm trying to use the following in perl but it doesn't seem to be working. How do I match the exact sring without any interpolation of any string characters? I tried quotes and \Q, \E but nothing works

```
$string=~ s/\`date +%s\`/anotherthinghere/;
```

for clarity, string I'm trying to match is

```
`date +%s`
```

Oh, forgot to mention that `date +%s` is in a variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must have misused the `\Q` .. `\E` specifiers, as that is exactly what you want

I think, from what you say, that you have `` `date +%s` ``, and the backticks have been eaten by the markdown

In that case, this code will do what you want. The variable interpolation is done *first*, before and interpretation of the special characters

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = 'xxx `date +%s` yyy';

my $pattern = '`date +%s`';

$string =~ s/\Q$pattern/anotherthinghere/;

print $string;
```

**output**

```
xxx anotherthinghere yyy
```

Comment: What I was doing wrong was escaping the backquotes inside the \Q and \E. I removed them and it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If I well understand your question, how about:

```
my $var = q/`date +%s`/;
my $string = q/foo `date +%s` bar/;
$string =~ s/\Q$var/another/;
say $string;
```

**output:**

```
foo another bar
```